# JPA lazy loding is not working in one to many

Tags: hibernate, jpa, fetch

JPA lazy loading is not working in `@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY` association. Only need to load parent object without child object

```
    Parent Object - Emp

        @MappedSuperclass
        public class Emp implements Serializable {

        @Basic(optional = false)
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Id
        @Column(name = "emp_id", unique = true, nullable = false,length = 10)
        public BigInteger getEmpId() {
            return empId;
        }

        public void setEmpId(BigInteger empId) {
            this.empId = empId;
        }


        @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REMOVE},fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name = "ll_id", nullable = false , insertable = true)
        @PrivateOwned
        public List<DocumentData> getDocumentDataList() {
        return documentDataList;
        }
        }

Child - DocumentData - it has parent table primary key.

public class DocumentData implements Serializable {

    protected static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private BigInteger documentId;
    private BigInteger empId;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Id
    @Column(name = "doc_id", unique = true, nullable = false,length = 10)
    public BigInteger getDocumentId() {
        return DocumentId;
    }

    public void setDocumentId(BigInteger documentId) {
        this.documentId = documentId;
    }

    @Column(name = "emp_id",length = 10)
    public BigInteger getEmpId() {
        return empId;
    }

    public void setEmpId(BigInteger empId) {
        this.empId = empId;
    }   
}
```

SQL query - select o from EMPData o where 1 = 1 - issue is load parent object with child. Is there any way to load only parent

Comment: Could you please show a code that load the parent object.

Comment: Please show the code for all entities

Comment: What conrete experiment makes you think that lazy loading is not working? My gess is that you confuse "lazy loading" (which means that, as soon as you or your JSON mapper or whatever will call a method of the list to iterate on it for example, the data will be loaded) with "no loading at all and replace the actual list of documents by an empty list", which doesn't exist in JPA.

Comment: added code. and two object. we used jpsql to write query

Comment: LazyLoading is default fetc hstrategy for non 1-1 relations. So unless you specify otherwise, it is lazy loaded (and it works).

Comment: Your code *already* uses lazy loading. What you need to do if you want to fix your issue is to answer my question: what concrete experiment makes you think that lazy loading is not working? The issue is not a lazy-loading issue. It's a misunderstanding of what is means and of what your non-posted code does.

Comment: @SSSS simply speakig - what JB NIzet is sayig is that most probably whatever you do to check if relation was lazy loaded causes relation to be initialized. This is how it works. Its like "dont take that relation untill someone will try to access it". In your case eg writing to json or looking it up in debugger can trigger lazy fetch.